# How to programatically update time offset in a Featurized Rule?

Tags: rules, features

I have a [rule](https://drupal.org/project/rules) that compares the value of a date field to the current date. I also have a custom module with a config form that allows the user to set a number of hours of time offset. The rule is exported using Features, and I've edited the rule definition in the Features module to use the user-defined variable instead of hardcoding a value into the rule.

The only problem is now, in order to update the rule to match user-defined offset config, the feature that contains the rule has to be reverted. This is too much complication for the users, so I need to figure out a way to make the Rules config match my users' config without reverting a feature.

How can this value be updated?